# Java: Convert JSON object to Custom JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, soap-client

Converted SOAP response to JSON (using API), so right now wanted custom JSON response where delete some attributes and change field names. like below examples.

Example:

```
{
  "s:Envelope": {
    "xmlns:s": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
    "s:Body": {
      "Response": {
        "xmlns": "http://www.tempuri.org/",
        "Result": {
          "xmlns:a": "http://wwww.datacontract.org/",
          "a:CodeSet": [
            {
              "a:FullDescription": {
                "i:nil": true
              },
              "a:AgeFrom": {
                "i:nil": true
              },
              "a:ShortDescription": {
                "i:nil": true
              },
              "a:Code": "111111",
              "a:LongDescription": "Have a Nice Day",
              "a:EffectiveDate": "01/01/2017"
            },
            {
              "a:FullDescription": {
                "i:nil": true
              },
              "a:AgeFrom": {
                "i:nil": true
              },
              "a:ShortDescription": {
                "i:nil": true
              },
              "a:Code": "222222",
              "a:LongDescription": "Long Working Day",
              "a:EffectiveDate": "01/01/2018"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To:

```
   {
  "data": [
    {
      "CODE": "111111",
      "EFFECTIVE_DATE": "2017-01-01",
      "TERM_DATE": "9999-12-31",
      "AGE_FROM": "true",
      "SHORT_DESC": "HND",
      "LONG_DESC": "Have a Nice Day"
    },
    {
      "CODE": "2222222",
      "EFFECTIVE_DATE": "2018-01-01",
      "TERM_DATE": "9999-12-31",
      "AGE_FROM": "true",
      "SHORT_DESC": "LWD",
      "LONG DESC": "Long Working Day"
    }
  ]
}
```

Suggestions on easy way to convert it, means any API or annotations which does it?
Note: Response time already taking more than 15 secs.

Comment: Pass your XML to an object, then the object to a JSON. What's the issue with it?

Answer (score 0):

Do as below

1. Write two classes which map  the two json Strings.
2. Convert the First json  String to its Corresponding json  object
3. Write a logic to Map the Object from Step 2 to your second Object
4. Convert Your second object to JSon String.

Note : There are many ways to convert To/From json Java object From/To Json String, and there are plenty  resources  online to look into. I left that for you to research what is best for your need.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use JSON-P 1.1. Here is an example from Adam Bien's blog:

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonArrayBuilder;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
//...

@Test
public void jsonObjectUpdate() {
    String key = "update";
    String JAVA_EE_8 = "is easy with Java EE 8";

    JsonObject initial = Json.createObjectBuilder().
        add(key, "was hard in Java EE 7").
        build();

    JsonObject updated = Json.createObjectBuilder(initial).
        add(key, JAVA_EE_8).
        build();

    assertThat(updated.getString(key), is(JAVA_EE_8));
    assertThat(updated.size(), is(1));
}
```

Full article is here: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/updating_jsonobjects_with_json_p

Or, if you want a more object-oriented aproach, you should add your own implementation of JsonObject (this is again JSON-P specification). Your implementation would take in the ctor the initial JsonObject and implement logic for extracting and returning that `data` JsonArray from it.